# Explicitly-sized data types (internal kernel ones) vs. primitive datatypes

Tags: c++, c, c++11, com

In a C++ project I saw the Explicitly sized Datatypes, like

```
 const S32 RET_ALIVE_INITIAL = 0;
 const S32 RET_ALIVE_SUCCESS = 1;
 const S32 RET_ALIVE_FAILURE = -1;
 const S32 MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 10000;
```

> S32 isAlive();

And also while learning Microsoft COM data types, where we use different datatypes like.

> System.UInt64
>
> System.Int32

So my Question is: what is the difference between these data types and primitive data (basic data) types like `int`, `float`, etc?

What advantages will get, and how it effect the system architecture means will it depend on the system architecture?

Or simply whats the difference? Can it be converted to primitive data types?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's the difference between what data types and what *derived* data types? C & C++ provide fixed width, 2's complement data types too in the `stdint.h` and `cstdint` headers.

Comment: Reading this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/694576) you'd learn that the size of the primitive integer types may vary from platform to platfrom. To get around this uncertainty types with a defined width were introduced.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question too.  What does _"our derived data types"_ mean?

Comment: @Praetorian Derived means basic data types like int float char etc.

Comment: Why are you calling basic, or primitive data tyoes *derived*? They're just about the farthest you can get from something that can actually be called *derived*. The `S32` is most likely a `typedef`, maybe a macro, for one of those basic data types, whichever one happens to be a signed 32-bit integer on that platform. You should read more about the types that `stdint.h` provides; for instance, an analogous type would be `int32_t`, which on most platforms, is a `typedef` for `int`. The types you're calling *derived types* form the basis of all other types.